# paralax effect in pure css doesnt work on firefox

Tags: html, css, transform, parallax, perspective

I want to create a simple paralax effect on my website.
Check this code please and please help : why this parallax effect doesnt work during scrolling this page?

This problem is because when I scrolling the page one element inside can not scroll faster then other element inside. I do not know why this can not work... Could you help me in this problem?

```
<body>
    <div class="parallax">
        <div class="parallax_layer parallax_layer_back">
            ...<br><br>
            Adam
        </div>
        <div class="parallax_layer parallax_layer_base">
            ...<br><br>
            Marina
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .parallax {
        perspective: 2px;
        -moz-perspective: 2px;
        height: 120vh;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
        background: rgba(100, 100, 0, 0.5);
    }
  
    .parallax_layer {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
  
    .parallax_layer_base {
        top: 100px;
        background: rgba(0, 200, 109, 0.5);
        transform: translateZ(0px);
        -moz-transform: translateZ(0px);
    }
          
    .parallax_layer_back {
        background: rgba(100, 200, 209, 0.5);
        transform: translateZ(-2px);
        -moz-transform: translateZ(-2px);
    }
          
</style>
```

Comment: just came across this [example](https://codepen.io/qqqqqqq/pen/RwoPMvG) works in Chrome but not in Firefox.   however [this one](https://codepen.io/yagoestevez/pen/EdgRMX) _does_ work in both browsers!